# Handling received message in running thread

Tags: java

I have Threads that listens to incoming HTTP messages , i want to enable other developer that use my code to be able to use the messages that i received in any time. I saw in some mobile OS you can implement class and override onRecive function to receive the messages .

is this the right architecture to use in this case? if yes how could i implemented and if its not what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

You can have an interface called `MessageListener`:

```
public interface MessageListener{
    void onMessage(String message);
}
```

Users of your library will create their own MessageListeners and will implement the `onMessage` method which defines what should be done when a message is received. They will also set (or register) this MessageListener with your "threads" before they are started.

Now whenever your thread gets a message, it will notify the listener(s) registered with it by calling the `onMessage` method.

Comment: i develop for BB and i notice that Observer is not included in the API, could you explain more how they could register MessageListener with my thread. Thanks

Comment: @Fevos In your thread class, you should provide a method called `addListener(MessageListener l)`. They will then call this method with their own implementation of MessageListener, before starting the thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a interface which another develoepr can implement and register with your code to be notified when a new message etc has arrived.  There are any number of ways this can be achieved.

You could use the built in Observable class. or you could do something like this.

```
public interface Listener<T> {
    public void onEvent(T t);
}

public class Listenable<T> {
    private final List<Listener<T>> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener<T>>();

    public void register(Listener<T> listener) {
        if (!list.contains(listener)) list.add(listener);
    }

    public void unregister(Listener<T> listener) {
        list.remove(listener);
    }

    public void onEvent(T t) {
        for (Listener<T> tListener : list) 
            tListener.onEvent(t);
    }
}
```

The caller could implement the Listener interface or provide an object which does. It then registers this with the Listenable. The listenable can notify all registered listeners.

Comment: what i understand is to make an interface and the user could implemented the thing that im wondering about how the user link (register) the implemented methode with my thread. Thanks